# node import error outside a module with typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, typeorm

i am writing a nodejs typescript application using typeorm.
when i debug the application using webstorm  i call in server.ts a typeorm method createConnection and i get an error:
"cannot use import statement outside a module"
pointing to the import statement in an entity file:

```
      import { BeforeInsert... } from 'typeorm'
      
       @Entity()
       export class test{....}
```

here is what i tried:

1. change in ormconfig.json
   entities: ['src/**/*.entity.ts']
   to:
   entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js']
2. changes in package.json in scripts:

   "start": "node dist/server.js"

to:

```
"start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
```

3. ran from the command line:
   node dist/server.js
4. delete dist and build

all of these returned me the error "cannot use import statement outside a module"

1. how can i debug the program using webstrom?
2. how can i run this program?

i use node 12.16.3

my ormconfig:

```
{
  "type":"mongodb",
  "database": "test",
  "syncroonize": true,
  "logging": true,
   "entities": ["src/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2019",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "moduleResultiuon": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadate": true,
  "exprimaentalDecorators: true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true

 }
```

thanks

Comment: what does your tsconfig.json file look like?

Comment: added tsconfig.. please help......

Comment: I see a lot of misspellings, and you have no  rootDir set. this is my tsconfig, maybe give it a shot.

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
          "es5",
          "es6"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dest",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
      }
    }